# Why does it make a difference to use a static char const* instead of a string literal here?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

In the code below (with a link [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n9DIYxrhz1APt3io)) g++ produces an executable that prints garbage (while clang++ doesn't) unless I define `THIS_WORKS`.

The difference being,

```
#ifdef THIS_WORKS
  static char const* empty_string = "";
  return { separator, empty_string, args... };
#else
  return { separator, "", args... };
#endif
```

It greatly surprises me that this even *can* make a difference. The only reasons that I can come up with is that this has be a compiler bug, or is Undefined Behavior in the program itself that I am missing.

What is going on here? Why does g++ print garbage instead of a leading `""`?

Here is the complete compilable code snippet:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ...Args>
struct Join
{
  char const* m_separator;
  std::tuple<Args const&...> m_args;
  Join(char const* separator, Args const&... args) : m_separator(separator), m_args(args...) { }
  template<size_t ...I> void print_on(std::ostream& os, std::index_sequence<I...>);
};

template<typename ...Args>
template<size_t ...I>
void Join<Args...>::print_on(std::ostream& os, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  (..., (os << (I == 0 ? "" : m_separator) << std::get<I>(m_args)));
}

template<typename ...Args>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Join<Args...> comm)
{
  comm.print_on(os, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
  return os;
}

template<typename ...Args>
Join<Args...> join(char const* separator, Args const&... args)
{
  return { separator, args... };
}

template<typename ...Args>
Join<char const*, Args...> join_more(char const* separator, Args const&... args)
{
#ifdef THIS_WORKS
  static char const* empty_string = "";
  return { separator, empty_string, args... };
#else // THIS_DOES_NOT
  return { separator, "", args... };
#endif
}

template<typename... Args>
void test_func(Args... args)
{
  std::cout << join_more(", ", args...) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  test_func(1, 2, 3);
}
```

The expected output is:

> , 1, 2, 3

Namely, `join_more` is intended to print a template pack where each argument is prepended with a comma. `join` doesn't print a leading comma for the first argument.

Comment: I'd recommend running this with GCC or Clang's address sanitizer and seeing what that has to say. It sounds like something that could be caused by memory lifetime issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version with `THIS_WORKS` defined is fine, but yes, without `THIS_WORKS` the program has undefined behavior.

The code calls the specialization `join_more<int, int, int>`, which returns a `Join<char const*, int, int, int>`. That class type has a member of type `std::tuple<char const* const&, int const&, int const&, int const&>`. The `int const&` elements refer to the `args...` of `test_func`, and those live as long as needed.

But the first element of the `tuple` is not so lucky. It's true the string literal's `const char[1]` object containing `'\0'` has no effective end to its lifetime. But the actual tuple element is a `char const* const&` reference. With `THIS_WORKS`, it refers to the object `empty_string`, which also lives long enough.  Without `THIS_WORKS`, the compiler needs to create a temporary `char const*` object to initialize the second argument of constructor `Join<const char*, int, int, int>::Join(char const*, char const* const&, int const&, int const&, int const&)` for the `return` statement of `join_more`. Then the lifetime of that temporary `char const*` object immediately ends on function return.

Comment: Brilliant... I've been going at this for an hour and all the time since I posted my question but had not found the answer yet. Thank you!